# Script to convert CSV to XLS

Tags: vb.net, excel, vbscript, ssis

Have a need to automate conversion of CSV files to XLS. The CSV files (which contain text qualifiers) will be automatically downloaded from a SFTP site and pushed to fixed width files for AS400 integration.  The customer currently has someone manually log into SFTP site, download file(s), open in Excel and save as XLS.  They have no control of original format or naming so the script must be able to convert files regardless of file name and/or number of files.  Am looking to automate the manual process or remove text qualifiers to help manage column mapping discrepancy.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

The customer uses SSIS as their development tool.  I apologize if the post is not clear. Am a newbie.  Thanks!

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with?  Currently this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: Agreeing with @StevenDoggart, this could be as involved as a macro, or as simple as opening the CSV files with excel.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Am trying to automate process so that users don't have to download and manually save as XLS.  Original CSV files have embedded qualifiers (") and were instructed to download the files , open each file, and save as XLS because this process break out each column correctly and can be fed to customer's ERP.  Tried stripping out qualifiers but thought opening file automatically would be an option to help resolve.  Please advise.

Comment: So you want to provide a solution that will automatically convert these downloaded files to xls files?

Comment: @Jaycal, Yes I want to automate this process. The easiest solution would be to copy the manual process since the files save in a format easy to work with for the AS400 developer.  Please advise and thank again.

Comment: Can you provide sample input data? It's possible to handle this with VBScript/Excel. However Excel can be rather picky about what it accepts as CSV, so simply opening the file with Excel may not work as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for something like this:

```
Sub SaveAsXLSX()

Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

'Allows you to pick the CSV file from wherever it's been saved.
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\YourUsername\Documents" & "\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
        For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem)
        Next
End With

'Saves the file as an .xlsx file.
wbSource.SaveAs Filename:="Random Name.xlsx", FileFormat:=51

End Sub
```

Just remember to change the `.InitialFileName` to the file path of wherever you're saving these downloads.

Comment: Want to thank you all for the responses. Greatly appreciated. After modifying the script a bit ARich's post worked for this purpose.  Thanks again!